# migrate windows based kiosk host to ubuntu, OTA

Tags: windows, migration

I consult with a company that has thousands of locations with a windows kiosk based application.  Were looking to migrate the app to be linux hosted but it's prohibitive to visit each location to install linux.  If we can do this conversion over the air, we'd be on our way.

Can any suggest tools or techniques to make this happen. We can build tools ourselves if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PXE booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) with specially prepared [LTSP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP) image.

Can't answer more, as it is very complex and broad question.